# Trying to Move 1 Selected Object in Blender Drags Other Faces It's Touching

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

If I create or duplicate an object that's touching other faces on objects in edit mode, it drags the faces it's touching with it. This just started happening in the middle of me making a haunted house model. Here's a video with the problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YsuNEOsiB40&feature=youtu.be

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the *Proportional Editing* button on the bottom horizontal menu bar (a blue sphere icon)